# Adding Facebook Connect to a CodeIgniter website

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, facebook

I'm having problems trying to connect my website to Facebook. What I would like it to do is allow users to augment their accounts by connecting them to Facebook (I do not need people to be able to login with Facebook, I am using OpenID instead). My website runs in the CodeIgniter framework.

What I will do is remove everything that I've tried and walk you through my steps up until it stops working.

**Step 1: Set up the JavaScript SDK and XFBML**

First I add a reference to the FBML spec to my `<html>` tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Then, after my `<body>` tag, I add:

```
<script src="http://static.new.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now here comes the first problem I had [but have now solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104455/why-is-my-facebook-connect-button-taking-me-to-the-wrong-url). The problem was that the docs for the JavaScript SDK say that the `FB.init()` method [requires the appId](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init) as a parameter, but this turned out to be incorrect. I needed to pass my apiKey instead. So this is the code that I ended up with, that goes before my `</body>` tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    FB.init({
        apiKey  : '<?php echo $this->config->item('facebook_api_key'); ?>',
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        xfbml  : true
    });

</script>
```

Now I can add XFBML entities to my pages, such as `<fb:login-button></fb:login-button>` which works just as expected. I click it and it pops up a box asking if I want to allow my website to access my Facebook profile. I say yes, and then if I check my Application Settings in Facebook, I can see that my website has been added.

So this step works fine.

**Step 2: Set up the PHP library**

Okay, so now I need to add the PHP library. So a quick google search for 'codeigniter facebook library' reveals [Elliot Haughin's library](http://www.haughin.com/code/facebook/). I download the files, put them all in the right places then get to work on loading the library.

Now the current problem occurs. I add the following code (taken from the example given with the library) to my controller constructor so that it happens on every page:

```
$this->load->library('facebook_connect');
$this->data['fb_user'] = $this->facebook_connect->user;
$this->data['fb_userid'] = $this->facebook_connect->user_id;
```

But if I do `print_r($this->data['fb_user']);` I get nothing. Ever. Whether I'm logged into facebook, logged out, logged in and added my site to my profile, etc. etc. etc. The user and user_id are never set. I don't get any errors though.

As far as I'm aware, the values are supposed to be set so that I know whether the person browsing my site is logged into their facebook account. If they are, I can see if they've allowed my application. If they've allowed it, I can let them disconnect from my site, if not, I can let them connect. But I can't do anything if these variables aren't populated.

I've tried poking around inside the source of the library, but I really can't get my head around it. And I'm hoping that the actual solution for this won't involve hacking the library apart. I'd expect a CodeIgniter specific library to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Facebook has a official php-sdk that works well within codeigniter... http://jondavidjohn.com/b/P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this Facebook Library](http://github.com/dannybtran/CI_Facebook) by Danny Tran hosted on Github. Works wonders and is fairly easy to get set-up.

Answer (score 2):

You are loading the new (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js) and the old (http://static.new.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php) JS SDKs. Remove the reference to the older one. The new JS SDK will set a signed cookie, which can be read (securely) using the new PHP SDK: http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk. This auth example for the JS SDK might help too: http://fbrell.com/auth/all-in-one

Answer (score 2):

These links might solve your any facebook programming problems.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/

http://realfoot.com/facebook_connect/login_page.php

[Facebook Login Button: Can I prevent auto page reload after login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197754/facebook-login-button-can-i-prevent-auto-page-reload-after-login)

[Codeignitor, Facebook javascript SDK, PHP SDK Redirect after facebook login doesnt getUser() until refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047691/codeignitor-facebook-javascript-sdk-php-sdk-redirect-after-facebook-login-does)

http://www.braintilt.com/fbcookies.php

http://www.permadi.com/blog/2011/02/facebook-authenticationlogin-process-in-popup-or-not/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

http://ottopress.com/wordpress-plugins/simple-facebook-connect/

http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-integrate-with-facebook-connect/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/facebook-integrate/

http://worldpointx.com/2009/05/authentication-rot/

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

http://www.justin-klein.com/projects/wp-fb-autoconnect

http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-12130-problems-connecting-to-facebook

http://en.kioskea.net/s/Cannot+login+on+website+using+facebook+login

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=310bc994b12d2750&hl=en 
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=310bc994b12d2750&hl=en

http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=142036

http://www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/229/CakePHP_Facebook_Plugin_Auth_Facebook_and_more

Answer (score 1):

Did you add xd_reciever file to your public directory????

Probabiliy this may causing the problem bcoz xd_reciever deifine the channel between your app to facebook.

Answer (score 1):

This post may be useful for you. [Check it out.](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-javascript-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/)