# Codeigniter, Facebook javascript SDK, PHP SDK Redirect after facebook login doesn't getUser() until refresh

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

The process is as follows.

```
1. User clicks Facebook Login button
2. User signs in and grants perms
3. Facebook redirects uses FB.Event.subscribe auth.login to redirect my login controller
4. My login controller loads the fbconnect module and chains the method Connect()
5. Connect() Checks if there is a facebook user using getUser() and if true checks if they are an existing user to log them in or returns false if no facebook user was found.
```

Everything works except the only problem is after being redirected to the login page Connect returns False when it should in fact be true sine the fbuser is logged in and has granted perms. If I refresh however everything works, the user is logged in if exists or if new is sent to the signup page. Below is my code..

```
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      //initializing API
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: '(My app id)', status: true, cookie: true,
                 xfbml: true, // channel.html file
                 oauth  : true
                 });
                 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                 window.location='http://www.(Mysite).com/login';
                 });
                 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                 window.location='http://www.(Mysite).com/logout';
                 });
                 };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
```

Fbconnect.php

```
class Fbconnect extends MX_Controller {
public $fb_user = null;
public $fb_user_id = null;

// Initilize Fabebook
public function __construct() 
{   
    parent::__construct();
    $this->config->load("facebook");
    require 'facebook.php';

    $this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId' => $this->config->item('appId'),
      'secret' => $this->config->item('Secret')
    ));


    // Get user from FB
    $this->fb_user_id = $this->facebook->getUser();

    if ($this->fb_user_id):
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $this->fb_user = (object)$this->facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $this->fb_user = null;
      }
    endif;

}


public function connect(){

    // Check for FB object
    if($this->fb_user):
        // FB Object found
            // Check if user exists
            $this->load->model('facebook/m_facebook');
            $user = $this->m_facebook->getUser($this->fb_user->id);

            // If we find a user and fb connect is true
            if($user):
                // user found log them in
                if($this->ion_auth->login($user->username, $user->password, true, true)):
                   redirect('', 'refresh');
                endif;
            else:
            // There is a fb object & the user is not logged in & doesnt exist in db yet must be new 
                redirect('signup/facebook', 'refresh');
            endif;
    else: 
        // No FB user or user not logged in                                  
        return false;
    endif;    
}
```

The auth/login code (just the part that involves facebook)

```
 $this->load->module('facebook/fbconnect')->connect();
```

Comment: What browser are you using? FB are fixing issues where the cookie is not read the first time it's retrieved from the SDK (you have to refresh for it to work).

Answer (score 6):

Well I seem to have figured this out. I made this change to the javascript:

```
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
    });
});
```

I guess that by adding the FB.api('/me', function(response){}); it somehow made the getUser() return true. If anyone else is having getUser() return 0 try this. Anyway I hope this helps others :)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but I only use the PHP SDK. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem in that case?